# How to sum all values in column A where column B = Column C

Tags: vba, ms-access

Q:How to sum all values in column A where column B = Column C. I have a query that lists a primary key and foreign key. I would like to sum all values where the foreign key equals the primary key. The product of this sum should be populated at the end of the row for every foreign key value. Access Database, VBA.

This is what I have:

```
SUM([$Amount](IIF([TableA].[Primary_Key]=[TableB].[Foreign_Key],0,0)
```

enter image description here

Comment: Such that all foreign keys of the same value have the same [SUM$Amount_Product]

Comment: What do you mean by 'product of this sum' - what product? Did you mean to say 'result of this sum'? And if you want on each row, do an aggregate query of the table with the Amount field then join that query to the other table. Edit your question to provide sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Really should not use punctuation and special characters in names (only exception is underscore), especially as first character.

`Sum(IIf([Primary_Key]=[ForeignKey], [$Amount], 0))`

If the query uses an INNER JOIN, then the only records returned will be those where the primary and foreign keys are the same and the IIf() is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you! But it did not execute 'Expr1: Sum(IIf([Contracts_Contract ID]=[Funding_String_Contract ID],[Funding_String_Amount],0))'. I get the error: "Cannot have aggregate function in GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Did you try INNER JOIN and no IIf() function as suggested? Post attempted SQL statement. Otherwise, in query Design View, remove Sum from the expression and change GROUP BY under that field to Sum. Then view the query in SQL View.

Comment: Thank you! But this still doesn't get me to where I want to be. I'm looking for an expression that sums all values in a query that share a foreign key/primary key. The current expression appears to only verify that the primary key and foreign key are the same as opposed to matching all other records where the primary key and foreign key are the same and providing a sum. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Statement = Sum(IIf([TableA].[PK]=[Table A].[FK],[TableA].[$_Amount],0))

Comment: That is not a complete query SQL statement. I don't understand what you mean by 'matching all other records'. Why would an INNER JOIN not resolve this?

Comment: You should edit question to include SQL statement and sample data.

Comment: In my table I have a series of records where the PK=FK and they all share the same value, however, in all of those records they each have a unique $ amount. I would like to sum all of the unique $ amounts based on the matching PK/FK value. (I'm very new and green to this so anything is a huge help!)

Comment: Again, try an INNER JOIN. Query designer should make building join and aggregate query simple. Can't help further if you won't provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide a sum of values associated with column A and column B a CROSSTAB QUERY was necessary. Crosstab queries can be setup manually or through the 'Create Query' wizard.